# TestFlight review process vs. App Store review process

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, testflight

Is it possible to pass the TestFlight review process and then fail the App Store review process with the same build?

In other words, if my build successfully passes the TestFlight review process, is it re-reviewed with more stringent requirements before being accepted into the App Store?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking *how/why Apple does something is outside the scope of what can be asked as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*

Comment: @Allan I disagree with the closure vote.  The OP's question is it possible to pass a TF review but fail the AS review.  It's not, in my view, asking *how* the reviews are done.  I think I provided the correct answer to that specific question.

Comment: @fsb - it's off topic because of the very first sentence:  *can I be sure that it will pass....*   Only **Apple** can answer that question and as such, should be directed to Apple.

Comment: @Allan I will edit the question.  fsb's answer was what I needed to know.

Comment: @Allan I can see that.  CFL_Jeff, can you [edit] your question to address Allan's point?  That will help ensure the question isn't closed and it could help others, also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because the TestFlight review is not as thorough or complete.

The assumption (based on what I've seen over a few years as a developer) is that builds in TF are still in development and things can change.  It's not a slam-dunk that builds will be accepted into TF because they do some review on them.

For the AppStore, a full review is performed again as if you didn't do TestFlight.  I'm guessing they review any notes from the TF team but I don't have proof of that.

So yes, it's possible to be in TF and then fail the AppStore review.  It’s also possible for the opposite to happen, you could struggle more in TF review and then breeze through the store process.